How can I make scroll to section work in NextJS using Shadcn drawer component?
I have a one page website, where I would like to scroll to sections when using the menu. Problem is, it doesn't scroll. Using the link in the browser does scroll to the page, but when clicking de link in the menu, it does nothing. Even not updating the link.
This is my navigation.tsx
"use client";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useScroll } from "@/contexts/scrollContext";
import { MenuIcon } from "lucide-react";
import {
  Drawer,
  DrawerClose,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerTrigger,
} from "./ui/drawer";

export default function Navigation({ className }: { className?: string }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const { setHash } = useScroll();

  const routes = [
    { name: "Home", path: "#top" },
    { name: "Wie zijn wij", path: "#who" },
    { name: "Wat doen we", path: "#what" },
    { name: "Wat maakt ons bijzonder", path: "#why" },
    { name: "Contact", path: "#contact" },
  ];

  const handleClick = (path: string) => {
    setHash(path);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <nav
      className={cn(
        "flex flex-col gap-4 items-end absolute right-20 top-8",
        className
      )}
    >
      <div className="rounded-full bg-mainPurple w-[50px] h-[50px] flex items-center justify-center text-white">
        <Drawer direction="right" open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
          <DrawerTrigger asChild>
            <MenuIcon />
          </DrawerTrigger>
          <DrawerContent>
            <DrawerHeader className=" flex flex-col justify-center gap-12 p-10 h-full">
              {routes.map((route) => (
                <DrawerClose key={route.path} asChild>
                  <Link
                    href={route.path}
                    className="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800 px-3 py-2 text-6xl  font-medium cursor-pointer"
                    onClick={() => handleClick(route.path)}
                    scroll={false}
                  >
                    {route.name}
                  </Link>
                </DrawerClose>
              ))}
            </DrawerHeader>
          </DrawerContent>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}



page.tsx
import BackgroundPattern from "@/components/background-pattern";
import ContactUs from "@/components/contact-us";
import H1 from "@/components/h1";
import Section from "@/components/section";
import SubHeaderLoop from "@/components/subheader-loop";
import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/toaster";
import WhatWeDo from "@/components/whatWeDo";
import WhoWeAre from "@/components/whoWeAre";
import WhyUs from "@/components/whyUs";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Section id="top">
        <BackgroundPattern />
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-8 min-h-screen md:h-auto">
          <H1>Fortius webdevelopment</H1>
          <div className=" h-[30px] text-2xl flex justify-center flex-nowrap overflow-hidden">
            <SubHeaderLoop />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Section>

      <Section id="who">
        <WhoWeAre />
      </Section>

      <Section id="what">
        <WhatWeDo />
      </Section>

      <Section id="why">
        <WhyUs />
      </Section>

      <Section id="contact">
        <ContactUs />
      </Section>
      <Toaster />
    </>
  );
}

layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Header from "@/components/header";
import Footer from "@/components/footer";
import { ScrollProvider } from "@/contexts/scrollContext";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Fortius Webdevelopment",
  description:
    "Fortius Webdevelopment biedt op maat gemaakte weboplossingen, van ontwerp tot implementatie, om uw online aanwezigheid te versterken en bedrijfsresultaten te verbeteren.",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className="scroll-smooth">
      <body className={`${inter.className} min-h-screen mx-[20px] md:mx-0`}>
        <main className="min-h-screen flex flex-col max-w-[1600px] mx-auto gap-20 md:gap-0">
          <ScrollProvider>
            <Header />
            {children}
            <Footer />
          </ScrollProvider>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


Context provider:
"use client";
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const ScrollContext = createContext<any>(null);

export const ScrollProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [hash, setHash] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleHashChange = () => {
      console.log("Hash changed:", window.location.hash);
      if (window.location.hash) {
        setHash(window.location.hash);
      } else {
        setHash(null);
      }
    };

    handleHashChange();
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", handleHashChange);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("hashchange", handleHashChange);
  }, [pathname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hash) {
      const targetId = hash.substring(1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        const target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (target) {
          target.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Target not found:", targetId);
        }
      }, 500); // Adjust the delay as needed
    }
  }, [hash]);

  return (
    <ScrollContext.Provider value={{ setHash }}>
      {children}
    </ScrollContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useScroll = () => useContext(ScrollContext);



Update 1:
I console logged the hell out of the website, created even a context provider for such a simple feature. Now I see that the Shadcn Drawer component is the issue. Does somebody has any idea how to make it work with the Drawer component?
Update 2:
After playing around. I got it working now. Because of the drawer closing it take a couple of ms. This happens asynchronously. So adding a delay to the useEffect in the context provider will fix it. I think using the context provider is overkill for this. But it works now. For anyone who is struggling with this. This is a solution.
